# phpSPO library - How to copy subfolders in Sharepoint

Tags: php

I am using the phpSPO library for sharepoint: https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

I am able to copy a folder along with it's files using:

```
    $credentials = new ClientCredential("MyCredentialsGoHere","MyCredentialsGoHere");
    $ctx = (new ClientContext("https://MyURL.sharepoint.com/enquiries"))->withCredentials($credentials);

    $sourceFolder = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents/Project Templates");
    $targetFolder = $sourceFolder->copyTo("Shared Documents/".$test, true)->executeQuery();
```

However it does not copy any subfolders.

I assume that I have to iterate through the subfolders of my source directory manually doing a copy for each one to the new target directory.
My starting point for this was to list the subfolders in a SharePoint folder:

```
    $credentials = new ClientCredential("MyCredentialsGoHere","MyCredentialsGoHere");
    $ctx = (new ClientContext("https://MyURL.sharepoint.com/enquiries"))->withCredentials($credentials);

    $sourceFolder = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents/Project Templates");
    $subfolders = $sourceFolder->getFolders()->executeQuery();

    foreach ($subfolders as $folder) {
        print_r($folder);
    }
```

However this doe not work as I expected (it produces no output) and my resources are exhausted.

Any pointers to help me solve the issue or an example of a finished solution would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop the folders in a folder:

```
        $parentpath = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents/Project Templates");
        $folders = $parentpath->getFolders();
        $ctx->load($folders);
        $ctx->executeQuery();
        foreach ($folders->getData() as $folder) {
            $display = $folder->getProperty("ServerRelativeUrl");
            echo ("File name: ".$display."<br/>");
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).